# PHP Get the first value of all arrays in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Here's a section my multidimensional array:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => Height [1] => 40 ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => Weight [1] => 15 ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => Ctr_Percent [1] => 15 ) 
)
```

What would the syntax be for just printing `height`, `weight`, and `ctr_percent`? I don't mean echoing it like:

```
echo $array[0][0];
echo $array[1][0];
```

Is there a way to iterate through the entire multidimensional array and echo out the first value of each child array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($main_array as $inner_array){
  echo $inner_array[0] . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Supposing you use php 5.3:

```
$first_elements = array_map(function($i) {
    return $i[0];
}, $data);
```

Otherwise you need to implement a callback function or just use plain old `foreach`

Comment: I think it should be noted that that works only if index 0 happens to be the key of the first element in the array. It simply doesn't return the first value of the subarray it just returns the value of the element with key 0 which might be the first element.

Comment: @Christoph the element with the index 0 of a numerically indexed array is semantically "the first value of the subarray". If the nested arrays are not numerically indexed - there is really no much sense to speak about their "order" at all.

Comment: php has an order for each array independant of it's keys e.g. in [1=>5,0=>3] the array in numerically index yet still key 1 is the first element not zero. You will always iterate over this implicit order using foreach not in sorted order of the keys. There are no plain arrays like in c like languages.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a one-liner:

```
array_map('array_shift', $array);
```

Will return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Height
    [1] => Weight
    [2] => Ctr_Percent
)
```

And here is another one:

```
array_combine(array_map('array_shift', $temp), array_map('array_pop', $temp))
```

Will return:

```
Array
(
    [Height] => 40
    [Weight] => 15
    [Ctr_Percent] => 15
)
```

Comment: Using `array_map()` to call `array_shift()` by function name becomes a problem from PHP8 and up. https://3v4l.org/42k5I  `array_column($array, 0)` should have been the technique of choice for a long time.

Answer (score 6):

Use [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column):

```php
$result = array_column($array, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $x) {
   echo $x[0]."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the function your looking for is `reset()` e.g.

```
array_map('reset', $array);
```

or

```
foreach ($array as $subarray)
    echo reset($subarray)."\n";
```

Note that this works even if 0 is not the first index of the array. E.g. `$a = [1=>5,0=>3]; echo reset($a);` would still `echo 5;`.

Comment: From PHP8.0, PHP emits Warnings when `array_map()` calls `reset()` by function name. https://3v4l.org/Z7PUVL

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it using `array_walk`

```
        function getFirstElement(&$val){
            $val = $val[0];
        }
        array_walk($data,'getFirstElement');
```

Now if you print $data like `print_r($data);` you will get result as below

```
Array
(
   [0] => Height
   [1] => Weight
   [2] => Ctr_Percent
)
```